# Get UTC time for different timezone in mysql format

Tags: javascript, mysql, datetime

With `dateObj.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ')` we can convert a date object to mysql datetime format in javascript. But the timezone is always considered as the client's (browser's) timezone.

I want to convert a date and time of different time-zones (not the browser's timezone) to UTC time and then to mysql time format.

Eg:
Alice is scheduling a meeting in New-York from Sydney. Alice enters New-York time as the input. Even thought the browser's location is Sydney, the javascript code has to assume the browser's location is in New-York and convert the date time to UTC, then to mysql format.

I can get current New-York time with, `dateObj.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/New_York'})`. But not sure what to do next. Seems to be something to do considering time differences...

Anybody knows how to do this?

Comment: check http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

So you want to always store the date in the utc representation of where the event occurred.

**To Save:**
You know Alice has her Time Zone set to a specific value, therefore, you need to convert from Alice's time zone to UTC. If Alice entered 11:59:59 PM for the meeting time then the time stored would be when it occurred in GMT, which would be +4/5 hours depending on whether DST is being observed. It sounds like using your solution you would need a function like `dateTimeUTC=FromSpecificTimeZoneToUTC(specificTimeZoneDateTime,'Eastern Standard Time')`

```
dateObj.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: '<TimeZone name for GMT>'})
```

**To View:**
Alice now has adjusted here Time Zone info to be in PST, which is GMT-8. Since we know the event occurred at 3:59:59 AM GMT we would need a function to convert from UTC back to a specific time, PST, this would yield 7:59:59 PM in Alices' changed config.
`dateTimeSpecific=FromUTCToSpecificTimeZone(uTCTimeZoneDateTime,'Pacific Standard Time')`

In my opionion you might be better served handling conversions like this on the server side where you have control over the tz info. I think a js might be too  inconsistent because the time information is based on the client computers regional settings, not the preferred timezone of the operation. Plus, time zone info is subject to change. I don't know how js handles those changes.